# Where does this distance difference come from

Tags: css-position

so I can not figure out why does those two ( below ) look differently if it is the same code, same page actually.

[image: The way it displays in google chrome device toolbar]

[image: The way it displays at actuall iPhone 4s]

Distance of that image gallery is decided by:
position:absolute;
top: 75px;

[edit]funny thing though is that, that the page displays exactly as in device toolbar on my android device .. which has similar resolution to iPhone4, why would safari(iPhone) read simple code as that in a different way [/edit]

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Otherwise, we can't help.

Comment: @MrLister thank you for your interest in my problem, although I think I have figured it out finally, it seems that the issue was due to the <ul> element (as it is a list of images ), when I have wrapped it into a div and used same css to position the <div> instead <ul> it renders the same at iOS and android

Comment: Ok, it doesn't really change anything xD, I`ll try to work on that example :)